# Automatically create correct class of object when pulling data with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Sorry for the bad title, I really don't know how to word it better.

I have a SQL table named `Posts` and a class named `Post`. A post can be multiple things such as a `Thread` or a `ThreadReply`, which are subclasses of Post but are all stored in the same Post table. To identify the type of Post it has a PostType field.

```
[Table(Name = "Posts")]
public class Post
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public PostType Type { get; set; }

    // ...
 }

 public class Thread : Post { /* ... */ };
 public class ThreadReply : Post { /* ... */ };
```

I use this to get the posts from the database in my `IPostsRepository`:

```
 db.GetTable<Post>(); // IQueryable<Post>
```

However they are all instantiated as `Post` (obviously). I want them to be instantiated based on their PostType, so that things like `Thread t = p as Thread;` will work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Note: a solution that returns a IQueryable<...> containing only one post type is not acceptable; it must be "mixed" as sometimes I have to work with all posts, regardless of their type

Comment: Use `IsDiscriminator` attribute to define table per Class Hierarchy. Check this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute.isdiscriminator.aspx and http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/10/01/linq-to-sql-inheritance.aspx

Comment: @Cybernate, you should post an answer so I can upvote it... and btw, wow, cool, didn't know you could do this with Linq to SQL....

Comment: @Cybernate: yeah, post it as an answer.. The first link TBH was very vague but the second one definitely answered my question.

Comment: @Jon and @Andreas: Added the comment as an answer. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`IsDiscriminator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute.isdiscriminator.aspx) attribute to define table per Class Hierarchy.

Comment: I think that second link is broken.  This alternate version seems to work though: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/10/01/linq-to-sql-inheritance.aspx